# What is wrong with my implementation of the knapsack problem

Tags: python, algorithm

items = [[profit, weight]...]

```
items = [[44,92], [46,4], [90,43], [72,83], [91,84], [40,68], [75,92], [35,82], [8,6], [54,44], [78,32], [40,18], [77,56], [15,83], [61,25], [17,96], [75,70], [29,48], [75,14], [63,58]]
max_weight = 269
def knapsack_bruteforce(items, max_weight):
    def backtrack(i, curr_profit, curr_weight):       
        if(i+1 >= len(items) or curr_weight + items[i+1][1] > max_weight):
            return curr_profit
            
        return max(backtrack(i+1, curr_profit + items[i+1][0], curr_weight + items[i+1][1]), backtrack(i+1, curr_profit, curr_weight))
        
    return backtrack(-1, 0, 0)
```

knapsack_bruteforce(items, max_weight) should return 550 as the maximum profit but I'm getting
528 instead.

Comment: Not related to the error but don't use keywords like `set`

Comment: And also it's a dictionary **not a set**

Comment: I don't think you're actually exhaustively trying all of the combinations the way that you seem to think you are, which means that you shouldn't expect to get the best possible solution.  It would help if you explained the thinking behind this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the second part of the `if` condition:

```
if(i+1 >= len(items) or curr_weight + items[i+1][1] > max_weight):
    return curr_profit
```

When the second condition is true, you should still allow the *second* recursive call to be done -- the one where this weight is not included -- as there might still be a way to add another item (that has less weight). But as you return immediately here, that attempt is never made.

Without changing more than necessary to your code, you can fix this, by bailing out (returning a negative number) when the weight excess has *already been made*. So split your `if` into two:

```
if curr_weight > max_weight:
    return -1
if i+1 >= len(items):
    return curr_profit
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you aren't exhaustively trying all the combinations; each time you remove an item, your recursive call needs to consider *all* the other items, not just the items *after* the one you removed.

Here's an example of a working brute-force solution; I added a `functools.cache` decorator (which requires immutable inputs, hence a tuple of tuples instead of a dict of lists) so I wouldn't have to wait all day for it to return the answer and make sure it works, but it should return the same answer without the memoization (just a lot more slowly).  Memoization makes it go faster because otherwise you end up re-computing the exact same intermediate answers (arrived at in slightly different orders) quite a few times.

The thing to pay attention to is that in that `max` call we're iterating over all of `items`, and doing the recursive call with `items[:i] + items[i+1:]`, i.e. *all the items except the i-th item*.

```
from functools import cache

@cache
def knapsack(items: tuple[tuple[int, int], ...], max_weight: int) -> int:
    if all(weight > max_weight for _profit, weight in items):
        return 0  # can't add anything to the sack

    return max(
        profit + knapsack(items[:i] + items[i+1:], max_weight - weight)
        for i, (profit, weight) in enumerate(items)
        if weight <= max_weight
    )


print(knapsack((
    (44,92), (46,4), (90,43), (72,83), (91,84), (40,68), (75,92),
    (35,82), (8,6), (54,44), (78,32), (40,18), (77,56), (15,83),
    (61,25), (17,96), (75,70), (29,48), (75,14), (63,58)
), 269))  # 550
```